Lost updates Sagemaker Feature Store
With AWS Sagemaker Feature Store, is there a risk of accidentally overwriting fields that are not intended to be changed? How is this typically prevented?
Example:
A feature set stores data on cars
Request A intends to update the price for Honda Accord 2025s to $40,000. It fetches the latest version in the feature set for Honda Accord where price was $45,000 and gas mileage was 40 mpg.
At almost the same time Request B starts. It intends to update the gas mileage to 45 mpg. It fetches the same latest record with price $40,000 and mileage 40 mpg.
Request A writes first. Request B then writes, but it doesn't know Request A set the price to $45k. It resets the price to $40k but updates mileage to 45 mpg.

Could you please add actual code to explain how are you implementing the two requests, and how the output from the API is different from your expectation?
